# Browserify Rails Error - ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, reactjs, npm

Recently i want to integrated NPM package in my rails application. I getting this problem :

[image]

I search in this forum if someone have same problem like me. Yes, i saw similar question being posted here but they're having different error.

Below is what i have in my application.js :

```html
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require react
//= require react_ujs
//= require components
//= require react-select
//= require react-dom
//= require classnames
//= require_tree .
$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });
```

Here's where i try to imported the package

```js
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var FileBase64 = require('react-file-base64');
var MembersNew = React.createClass(
{
 render()
 {
  return(
   <div>
   <h5>ACCOUNT DETAILS</h5>
   <hr/>
   <p>Fill in your member account details below</p>
   <b>Membership ID : </b>
   <div className="row">
   <div className="medium-6 columns">
     <label>Username*
                 <input ref="name" type="text"/>
              </label>
              <label>First Name*
                 <input ref="name" type="text"/>
              </label>
              <label>Last Name*
                 <input ref="name" type="text"/>
              </label>
              <label>Email Address*
                 <input ref="name" type="text"/>
              </label>
             </div>
```

I have mess up my gemfile for like below. Maybe this is why the problem occur :

```js
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

gem 'rails-assets-react-select','~> 1.0.0.rc.3', source: 'https://rails-assets.org'
gem 'rails-assets-react-dom', source: 'https://rails-assets.org'
gem 'rails-assets-classnames', source: 'https://rails-assets.org'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.2'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

gem 'react-rails'
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'responders'
gem 'foundation-rails'
# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
gem 'browserify-rails'
```

someone can help me to solve this error ?

Comment: Why there's no one willing to help me in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue you might be having is that the npm module that you are trying to install and use is an ES6 JS module. From your error log, I guess you are using Browserify to load your JS modules. IIRC Browserify out of the box only supports Common JS modules, which means you’ll have to run your JS through a tool like Babel or Babelify (babel’s browserify transform) to transform that ES6 module into an ES5 module with `module.exports` syntax.

Comment: Thank you, I successful get rid those error by following you advise. But i came out with another error which is cannot render those component.